# QML TreeView passes previous selection when clicking to collapse or expand

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have a QML `TreeView` containing some `onClicked()` logic that calls a Q_INVOKABLE function that takes in the current row number and the parent row number of the `TreeView` as parameters. The problem is that when I select something, and then I click to expand or collapse something. The previous values are still getting passed which sometimes makes the application crash. I've tried to call `treeView.selection.clearCurrentIndex()` and `treeView.selection.clearSelection()` in `onCollapsed()` and `onExpanded()` which deselects the item, but for some reason still passes the values from the previously selected item.

```
//main.qml

TreeView {
    id: treeView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: treeviewmodel
    selection: ItemSelectionModel {
        model: treeviewmodel
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "name_role"
        title: "Section Name"
    }
    onCollapsed: {
        treeView.selection.clearSelection() // deselects the item, but still passes the previous values
    }
    onExpanded: {
        treeView.selection.clearSelection()
    }
    onClicked: {
        console.log("Current Row: " + treeView.currentIndex.row + "Parent Row: " + treeView.currentIndex.parent.row)
        //I need something here that will set treeView.currentIndex.row and treeView.currentIndex.parent.row to -1
        //so that when I collapse or expand, -1 gets passed instead of the previous values
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should have some attributes to know when the user expanded or collapsed the tree in order to pass -1 in the `onClicked` event.

Comment: @Tarod What do you mean attributes? Can you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: If you need to pass -1 to your Q_INVOKABLE function after collapse or expand the tree, use a flag and set it to true after collapsing or expanding the tree. After that, when the `onClicked` event is called, check the flag: pass -1 to your Q_INVOKABLE function if it is true, or use the `treeView.currentIndex.row` and `treeView.currentIndex.parent.row` provided by QML if false. Change the flag value to false when required. Maybe I didn't understand the problem, but it's the solution I thought after reading the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting some additional flags (thanks @Tarod for the help). I had to save the value of the rows so that I could check if they changed. If they did not change, I would not call the function, so no obsolete values would get passed.

```
TreeView {
    id: treeView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: treeviewmodel
    property int currentRow: -1
    property int parentRow: -1
    property int lastCurrentRow: -1
    property int lastParentRow: -1
    selection: ItemSelectionModel {
        model: treeviewmodel
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "name_role"
        title: "Section Name"
    }
    onCollapsed: {
        currentRow = -1
        parentRow = -1
    }
    onExpanded: {
        currentRow = -1
        parentRow = -1
    }
    onClicked: {
        console.log("Row: " + treeView.currentIndex.row + " Parent : " + treeView.currentIndex.parent.row)
        //logic needed to not reselect last item when collpasing or expanding tree
        if (lastCurrentRow === treeView.currentIndex.row && lastParentRow === treeView.currentIndex.parent.row)
        {
            currentRow = -1
            parentRow = -1
        }
        else
        {
            lastCurrentRow = treeView.currentIndex.row
            lastParentRow = treeView.currentIndex.parent.row
            currentRow = treeView.currentIndex.row
            parentRow = treeView.currentIndex.parent.row
        }
        if (currentRow === -1 && parentRow === -1)
        {
            //nothing selected - do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            //omitted some additional logic
        }
    }
}
```